# JS one line 'for' and 'push' to array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
const matches = [
  {homeId: 123, awayId: 345},
  {homeId: 4343, awayId: 675},
  {homeId: 888, awayId: 999}
];
```

Then I want a new array with all `Id`. So I have this code:

```
let players = [];
for (m of matches) {    
  players.push(...[m.homeId, m.awayId]);
}
```

It's possible to do the same in one line? Something similar to javascript `map` (in my example I can't use map because final array has different length). Something like this:

```
const players = for (m of matches) {    
  players.push(...[m.homeId, m.awayId]);
}
```

Comment: Stop worrying about how many lines your code takes up. Worry more about whether it's understandable or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can map each object to its values with `Object.values`, then flatten with `.flat()`:

```js
const matches = [
  {homeId: 123, awayId: 345},
  {homeId: 4343, awayId: 675},
  {homeId: 888, awayId: 999}
];
const ids = matches.map(Object.values).flat();
console.log(ids);
```

Or with `flatMap`:

```js
const matches = [
  {homeId: 123, awayId: 345},
  {homeId: 4343, awayId: 675},
  {homeId: 888, awayId: 999}
];
const ids = matches.flatMap(Object.values);
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: Or just `.flatMap`.

Answer (score 2):

You could map with directly flatting the result.

```js
const
    matches = [{ homeId: 123, awayId: 345 }, { homeId: 4343, awayId: 675 }, { homeId: 888, awayId: 999 }],
    players = matches.flatMap(({ homeId, awayId }) => [homeId, awayId]);

console.log(players);
```

If you like to get **all values** from the objects, you could flatmap the values. The order of the values is defined by the inserteatimn order and the key values. Array like indices like positive 32 bit integer values are sorted first and then comes all other strings. At the end you get all values with `Symbols` as keys.

```js
const
    matches = [{ homeId: 123, awayId: 345 }, { homeId: 4343, awayId: 675 }, { homeId: 888, awayId: 999 }],
    players = matches.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(players);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.reduce()`

```js
const matches = [
  {homeId: 123, awayId: 345},
  {homeId: 4343, awayId: 675},
  {homeId: 888, awayId: 999}
];
let result = matches.reduce((a,v) =>  [...a, v.homeId, v.awayId] ,[])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `reduce`

```js
const matches = [
  {homeId: 123, awayId: 345},
  {homeId: 4343, awayId: 675},
  {homeId: 888, awayId: 999}
];


const ids = matches.reduce(function(accumulator , item){ accumulator.push(...[item.homeId , item.awayId]); return accumulator;} , []);

console.log(ids);
```